# a warning about func unc createDirectoryAtURL(value of the type '()' )

Tags: ios, swift, nsfilemanager

I am learner on iOS Development,today i try to code something[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xf52o.png) about FileManger,but this method return a type '()',how can i to resolve it?

the warning code as follow:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your call to `createDirectoryAtURL` does not have a explicit return value.  In Swift, that means it returns a `Void` which is represented by the empty tuple `()`. This is what your call should look like.

```
    let temp = NSTemporaryDirectory()
    let newDiretoryURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(temp + "/MyNewDirectory")
    try fileManager.createDirectoryAtURL(newDiretoryURL, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)
    print("Success")
  }
} catch {
  // handle errors here
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much,it is very helpful for me !^.^